# IShellView::SelectItem in Explorer after creating a new file

Tags: windows, winapi, contextmenu, shell-extensions

How can I select a file in Explorer after creating it in a `ContextMenu` shell extension?

I created the file using the [`IFileOperation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shobjidl_core/nn-shobjidl_core-ifileoperation) API, and tried to use [`IShellView::SelectItem()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-ishellview-selectitem) in the [`IFileProgressSink::FinishOperations()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-ifileoperationprogresssink-finishoperations) callback. But the file selection is only flashed briefly before it is unselected again. I assume Explorer notices some changes to files and updates the view.

I can semi-reliably(?) await 10ms after `FinishOperations` and then call `IShellView::SelectItem` to get it working, but is there a more sensible way to select files after file operations?

Comment: Have you tried selecting file after `IFileOperation::PerformOperations` returns, instead of relying on `IFileProgressSink` ?

Comment: Yes, I tried that one too. Even if I use `IShellView::SelectItem` after `PerformOperations` Explorer's view update happens after the file selection, and therefore unselects again.

Comment: Then I'm afraid there may not be a clean solution. But if the reason is that explorer posts this update message to itself by using a flavor of `PostMessage`, you could try posting you message to the same thread (I.e. STA thread from where Explorer calls your extension), after `PerformOperation` returns, so that message posted later is also handled later. Or you could try `WaitForInputIdle` on the process which loads your extension.

Comment: Just wait the 10ms (or even 20ms if you want to live dangerously!)

Comment: Did you try [SHCNF_FLUSH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shchangenotify#shcnf_flush) to ensure everybody has learned about the new file before you try to select it?

Comment: *But the file selection is only flashed briefly before it is unselected again.* - this say that really `IShellView::SelectItem` success, but after some another code deselect item or something else. i for test call `SelectItem(ILFindLastID(pidl), SVSI_SELECT )` just from `InvokeCommand` command and this is ok. folder view support delayed select. you not need wait any time. possible also set `IShellFolderViewCB` callback for folder view. inside `SFVM_FSNOTIFY::SHCNE_CREATE` can select, but still this will be delay select. you not show any your code. sure that problem in your implementation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Raymond Chen explained in the comment you can wait for changes using [SHCNF_FLUSH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shchangenotify#shcnf_flush).